# AWS SageMaker stop running without error/warning output

Tags: python, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

I am trying to do hyperparameter tuning of xgboost I installed using `pip install xgboost` directly in SageMaker notebook instance. Below is my code to do the hyperparameter tuning:

```
def train_xgb(X_train, y_train):
    """
    train an xgboosting model, optimize hyperparameters via grid search and return predicted results
    :param df: input dataframe containing all train/val/test data
    :return: trained model, predicted probability for y = 1 and predicted y label(0 for nopickup, 1 for pickup)
    """
    # grid search to find the best hyperparameter

    model = XGBClassifier()
    learning_rate =  [0.01] #0.001, 0.01, 0.1]
    max_depth = [15, 30, 45]
    n_estimators = [150, 200, 300]
    reg_alpha = [0.01] #[0.01, 0.1, 0.5]
    reg_lambda = [5] #[0.1, 0.5, 5]
    min_child_weight = [0.5] #[0.01, 0.1, 0.5]
    subsample = [0.5] #, 0.7, 0.9]
    colsample_bytree = [0.7] #[0.7, 0.5, 0.9]
    scale_pos_weight= [2]
    param = dict(learning_rate=learning_rate, n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth, reg_alpha=reg_alpha,
                      reg_lambda=reg_lambda, min_child_weight=min_child_weight, subsample=subsample,
                      colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree, scale_pos_weight=scale_pos_weight)

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid = param, scoring='roc_auc', cv=StratifiedKFold(10))
    print('Time before grid search: ', datetime.now())
    result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('Time after grid search: ', datetime.now())
    # summarize results
    print("Best %f using %s" % (result.best_score_, result.best_params_))

    # for initial scan
    # model = XGBClassifier(colsample_bytree=0.9, learning_rate=0.01, max_depth=15, min_child_weight=0.5, n_estimators=50,
    # reg_alpha=0.01, reg_lambda=5, subsample=0.7, scale_pos_weight=2)

    best_xgb = result.best_estimator_
    best_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

    return best_xgb
```

My training data is about 2 million rows and 160 columns, with the csv file of a size of around 0.5M KB (not big at all). The size of engineered dataframe is 1.5GB. The notebook instance I chose is ml.c5.18xlarge. However, the code will run at the `grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)` step for about 2hrs (I set 2 parameters and three values for each, so in total only 9 combinations) and stop without any warning/error output.

This seems to be a rare case as few people came across it when I asked around. However, no output makes it challenging to debug. I wonder 1) is it normal to take so long to run? 2) any hint why this happens and how to debug? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use the Tuning service in SageMaker for XGBoost (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-ex.html)? Running the tuning on the notebook instance is not a recommended option.

Comment: @Guy, I was trying to do both in parallel. Why running the tuning on the notebook instance is not a recommended option? Thanks!

Comment: The power of the cloud is in the ability to distribute the work and to pay for only what you use. If you run your experiments on your notebook instances, you are only utilizing a single (weak) instance. When you use the tuning service, you can rent a cluster for a few minutes and get a better answer faster.